# How to discover patterns in sequences of numbers

Tags: r, sequence

I have a list in R in which every single row is a half verse of bible text. The columns are: B(ook), C(chapter), V(erse), H(alf verse), and a1–a31. These columns with *a* plus an integer are codes that represent Hebrew cantillation marks.

What I need is a way to find patterns in the sequences of the numbers that tell me which combinations of integers occurs and how many times.

E.g.: how many times is 74 followed by 63; how many times is 63 preceded by 05.

Ideally it would also tell me combination of more than two. E.g.: how many times is 74 preceded by 05 which is preceded by 35.

Finally I'd need to chart this in some way.

Below are the header and the first 3 rows of the list.

```
B,C,V,H,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a17,a18,a19,a20,a21,a22,a23,a24,a25,a26,a27,a28,a29,a30,a31
Genesis,1,1,A,73,74,92 
Genesis,1,1,B,71,73,71,00
Genesis,1,2,A,81,71,3303,80,73,74,92
```

Comment: How high can the integers go (are they bounded?) I see one that’s 3303 (or is that a typo?).

Comment: No, it's not a typo. Some cells have 4, 6 or 8 numbers. This is because the specific word has 2, 3 or 4 accents and every accent has 2 numbers. The highest number is 74330305

Comment: If necessary I could change all the numbered codes into something more sensible. E.g. from 1–40 or so.

Comment: So you want to find the “n-grams”. I have no experience doing that, but I know the ‘tm’ package can find ngrams in text. I’m not sure if it can work with integers though.

Comment: Thanks Joe the n-gram packages does the job. It can handle numbers as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have a rather complicated solution, not sure it is the best one.
I makes use of `data.table` for reshaping and for the data manipulation.

the data:

```
library(data.table)

df <- setDT(read.table(text="
B,C,V,H,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7
Genesis,1,1,A,73,74,92,NA,NA,NA,NaN 
Genesis,1,1,B,71,73,71,00,NA,NA,NA
Genesis,1,2,A,81,71,3303,80,73,74,92",h=T,sep = ","))
```

I transform the data this way:

```
test <- melt(df,measure.vars = patterns("^a"))
plouf <- dcast(test[!is.na(value)],variable ~B+C+V+H,fill = "value")

   variable Genesis_1_1_A Genesis_1_1_B Genesis_1_2_A
1:       a1            73            71            81
2:       a2            74            73            71
3:       a3            92            71          3303
4:       a4            NA             0            80
5:       a5            NA            NA            73
6:       a6            NA            NA            74
7:       a7            NA            NA            92
```

I then create a vector of all combination of 3 successive numbers:

```
allcomb <- unlist(lapply(1:(nrow(plouf)-2),function(i){
  plouf[i:(i+2),lapply(.SD,function(col){paste(col,collapse = ",")}),.SDcols = grep("Genesis",names(plouf),value = T)]  
}))
```

It is a bit tricky:

```
plouf[1:3,lapply(.SD,function(col){paste(col,collapse = ",")}),.SDcols = grep("Genesis",names(plouf),value = T)]
```

concantenate the 3 first lines of all columns of plouf specified by `.SDcols = grep("Genesis",names(plouf),value = T)`

```
[1] "Genesis_1_1_A" "Genesis_1_1_B" "Genesis_1_2_A"
```

that is the columns beginning with Genesis. Doing that for all successive combination of 3 lines, and transforming the output into a vector gives me the vector `allcomb`. It contains combination with NA, that you can clean:

```
allcomb <- allcomb[!grepl("NA",allcomb)]

Genesis_1_1_A Genesis_1_1_B Genesis_1_2_A Genesis_1_1_B Genesis_1_2_A Genesis_1_2_A Genesis_1_2_A Genesis_1_2_A 
   "73,74,92"    "71,73,71"  "81,71,3303"     "73,71,0"  "71,3303,80"  "3303,80,73"    "80,73,74"    "73,74,92"
```

Having all the combination in text, you can use `table` to count the occurrence of each combination, leading to the results you wanted:

```
> table(allcomb)
3303,80,73 71,3303,80   71,73,71    73,71,0   73,74,92   80,73,74 81,71,3303 
     1          1          1          1          2          1          1
```

The vector `allcomb` contains the names in which you have the combination as a column name. You can thus find back each repetition :

```
sapply(unique(allcomb),function(comb){
  names(allcomb[grep(comb,allcomb)])}
  )

    $`73,74,92`
[1] "Genesis_1_1_A" "Genesis_1_2_A"

$`71,73,71`
[1] "Genesis_1_1_B"

$`81,71,3303`
[1] "Genesis_1_2_A"

$`73,71,0`
[1] "Genesis_1_1_B"

$`71,3303,80`
[1] "Genesis_1_2_A"

$`3303,80,73`
[1] "Genesis_1_2_A"

$`80,73,74`
[1] "Genesis_1_2_A"
```

Comment: This is quite sofisticated Denis. Thanks a lot, I will try this too.